# How to display folder content on a QTreeView with also the visible folder in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

Let's start by considering this simple snippet:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from pathlib import Path


class Proxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        return True


class Model(QFileSystemModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


class TreeView(QTreeView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = Path("c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc")
    # print("\n".join([str(p) for p in path.glob("**/*")]))

    app = QApplication([])

    proxy = Proxy()
    proxy.setSourceModel(Model())

    view = TreeView()
    view.setModel(proxy)

    proxy = view.model()
    model = proxy.sourceModel()
    model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
    index = model.index(str(path))
    view.setRootIndex(index)
    # view.setCurrentIndex(index)

    view.show()

    app.exec_()
```

I'd like to know how to display the whole content of the specified path as well as the path itself in the `QTreeView`, for instance, the QTreeView would display something like below:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC
│   hosts
│   lmhosts.sam
│   networks
│   protocol
│   services
│
└───BACKUP
        hosts_2018-08-24_18-35-52.txt
```

I know how I'd be able to display just the folder content but I'd also like to know how to show the root folder (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) itself.

Reason why my snippet is subclassing `QSortFilterPoxyModel` is because I understand that'd be the way to go here but I haven't made it work yet.

Could you explain how to fix the above snippet to accomplish this simple task?

Comment: From what I understand you, you want "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC" to be the root of the QTreeView and must be placed with its fullpath, and its subdirectories as Backup only its name, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi, In my post you can see i've printed the content of `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc` using the cmd `tree /f` and those are exactly the items I'd like to know how to display on the QTreeView, you can see there is 2 folders + 6 files listed there. At this point I'd know how to list the inner content of that folder (6files + 1folder), which could be listed without using QSortFilterProxyModel at all but that's not what i want... Does it make sense?

Comment: @eyllanescJust to clarify further, 2 folders {`c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`, `backup`} and 6 files {`hosts, lmhosts.sam, networks, protocol, services, hosts_2018-08-24_18-35-52.txt`}. But again... that's just a path to serve as example... i've used that particular path as it should be available on many windows versions

Comment: what is the fullpàth of backup?

Comment: @eyllanesc This [image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hxzz5oipwd77x64/explorer_2019-11-11_23-42-22.png) will explain it better